# ExtJS5 Namespace Confusion

Tags: extjs, namespaces

I am completely confused on the namespaces in ExtJS5 application.  I am using a common folder under the sencha workspace where I keep code I will be using for multiple pages (multiple SPA's).  In one application definition I have the following snippet:

```
Ext.define('Admin.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',   
    name: 'Admin',
    namespaces: ['ALT'],
    requires:[
        'ALT.GlobalLib',
.....
```

In my common/src folder I have a file called AltGlobalLib.js with the following snippet:

```
Ext.define('ALT.GlobalLib',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
/**/
/** Custom Field Manipulation Methods
/**/    
...
```

The file is loaded but I get a warning the the namespace for ALT.GlobalLib is missing and to add it to my Application Class namespace properties.Possible to get a firm example of how to properly separate the common code from the rest of the apps?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to `setPath` and designate the name and folder.

Check out the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-paths) on this.  And particular `setPath` on `Ext.Loader` in the [api docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath)

Here is an example:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('NameSpace', '../path/to/files');
```